# Meteor Accounts: error calling storedLoginToken() "undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts

I added the *Meteor-CollectionFS* lib to my Meteor project and noticed that file uploads are not working due to the error `Exception in delivering result of invoking '/cfs.images.filerecord/insert': TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

On digging about I could see that the `undefined is not a function` is being thrown from within *cfs_upload-http.js* by a call to `Accounts._storedLoginToken()`

I don't think that CollectionFS is the cause of the problem as I created a dummy project with the same dependencies as my project - when I call `Accounts._storedLoginToken()` from the *console* in the dummy project the login token is returned, however, when I make the same call from the console from my own project I get the error `TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Any ideas as to what could cause this?

Thanks in advance

Neil.

PS Worth pointing out that 1) in both the dummy and original projects, I was logged in when calling storedLoginToken 2) accounts packages and cfs collection packages are the same versions in both dummy and other project.

---

Update:

As requested, here are the dependencies for the dummy project (which works) and the real project (which doesn't). Note that I'm not actually *calling* the cfs stuff in the dummy project as I'm more focussed on the storedLoginText() problem (cfs problem looks like being a symptom of this, rather than the cause).

dummy project *packages*

meteor-platform
mizzao:bootstrap-3
underscore
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
accounts-password
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:ui
cfs:filesystem
iron:router
zimme:iron-router-active

dummy project *versions*

accounts-base@1.1.3
accounts-password@1.0.6
aldeed:autoform@4.2.2
aldeed:collection2@2.3.1
aldeed:simple-schema@1.1.0
anti:i18n@0.4.3
application-configuration@1.0.4
autoupdate@1.1.5
base64@1.0.2
binary-heap@1.0.2
blaze@2.0.4
blaze-tools@1.0.2
boilerplate-generator@1.0.2
callback-hook@1.0.2
cfs:access-point@0.1.43
cfs:base-package@0.0.27
cfs:collection@0.5.3
cfs:collection-filters@0.2.3
cfs:data-man@0.0.4
cfs:file@0.1.15
cfs:filesystem@0.1.1
cfs:http-methods@0.0.27
cfs:http-publish@0.0.13
cfs:power-queue@0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4
cfs:standard-packages@0.5.3
cfs:storage-adapter@0.1.1
cfs:tempstore@0.1.3
cfs:ui@0.1.3
cfs:upload-http@0.0.19
cfs:worker@0.1.3
check@1.0.4
coffeescript@1.0.5
ddp@1.0.14
deps@1.0.6
ejson@1.0.5
email@1.0.5
fastclick@1.0.2
follower-livedata@1.0.3
geojson-utils@1.0.2
handlebars@1.0.2
html-tools@1.0.3
htmljs@1.0.3
http@1.0.10
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3@1.2.31
id-map@1.0.2
iron:controller@1.0.7
iron:core@1.0.7
iron:dynamic-template@1.0.7
iron:layout@1.0.7
iron:location@1.0.7
iron:middleware-stack@1.0.7
iron:router@1.0.7
iron:url@1.0.7
jquery@1.11.3
json@1.0.2
launch-screen@1.0.1
livedata@1.0.12
localstorage@1.0.2
logging@1.0.6
meteor@1.1.4
meteor-platform@1.2.1
minifiers@1.1.3
minimongo@1.0.6
mizzao:bootstrap-3@3.3.1_1
mobile-status-bar@1.0.2
momentjs:moment@2.8.4
mongo@1.0.11
mongo-livedata@1.0.7
npm-bcrypt@0.7.7
observe-sequence@1.0.4
ordered-dict@1.0.2
raix:eventemitter@0.1.1
random@1.0.2
reactive-dict@1.0.5
reactive-var@1.0.4
reload@1.1.2
retry@1.0.2
routepolicy@1.0.4
service-configuration@1.0.3
session@1.0.5
sha@1.0.2
spacebars@1.0.5
spacebars-compiler@1.0.4
srp@1.0.2
stylus@1.0.6
templating@1.0.11
tracker@1.0.5
ui@1.0.5
underscore@1.0.2
url@1.0.3
webapp@1.1.6
webapp-hashing@1.0.2
wizonesolutions:underscore-string@1.0.0
zimme:iron-router-active@1.0.1

Real project *packages*

meteor-platform
mizzao:bootstrap-3
underscore
iron:router
sacha:spin
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3
accounts-password
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:collection2
zimme:iron-router-active
cfs:standard-packages
cfs:filesystem
cfs:ui

Real project *versions*

accounts-base@1.1.3
accounts-password@1.0.5
aldeed:autoform@4.2.2
aldeed:collection2@2.3.1
aldeed:simple-schema@1.1.0
anti:i18n@0.4.3
application-configuration@1.0.4
autoupdate@1.1.4
base64@1.0.2
binary-heap@1.0.2
blaze@2.0.4
blaze-tools@1.0.2
boilerplate-generator@1.0.2
callback-hook@1.0.2
cfs:access-point@0.1.43
cfs:base-package@0.0.27
cfs:collection@0.5.3
cfs:collection-filters@0.2.3
cfs:data-man@0.0.4
cfs:file@0.1.15
cfs:filesystem@0.1.1
cfs:http-methods@0.0.27
cfs:http-publish@0.0.13
cfs:power-queue@0.9.11
cfs:reactive-list@0.0.9
cfs:reactive-property@0.0.4
cfs:standard-packages@0.5.3
cfs:storage-adapter@0.1.1
cfs:tempstore@0.1.3
cfs:ui@0.1.3
cfs:upload-http@0.0.19
cfs:worker@0.1.3
check@1.0.3
coffeescript@1.0.5
ddp@1.0.13
deps@1.0.6
ejson@1.0.5
email@1.0.5
fastclick@1.0.2
follower-livedata@1.0.3
geojson-utils@1.0.2
handlebars@1.0.2
html-tools@1.0.3
htmljs@1.0.3
http@1.0.9
ian:accounts-ui-bootstrap-3@1.2.21
id-map@1.0.2
iron:controller@1.0.7
iron:core@1.0.7
iron:dynamic-template@1.0.7
iron:layout@1.0.7
iron:location@1.0.7
iron:middleware-stack@1.0.7
iron:router@1.0.7
iron:url@1.0.7
jquery@1.0.2
json@1.0.2
launch-screen@1.0.1
livedata@1.0.12
localstorage@1.0.2
logging@1.0.6
meteor@1.1.4
meteor-platform@1.2.1
minifiers@1.1.3
minimongo@1.0.6
mizzao:bootstrap-3@3.3.1_1
mobile-status-bar@1.0.2
momentjs:moment@2.8.4
mongo@1.0.11
mongo-livedata@1.0.7
npm-bcrypt@0.7.7
observe-sequence@1.0.4
ordered-dict@1.0.2
raix:eventemitter@0.1.1
random@1.0.2
reactive-dict@1.0.5
reactive-var@1.0.4
reload@1.1.2
retry@1.0.2
routepolicy@1.0.3
sacha:spin@2.0.4
service-configuration@1.0.3
session@1.0.5
sha@1.0.2
spacebars@1.0.4
spacebars-compiler@1.0.4
srp@1.0.2
stylus@1.0.6
templating@1.0.10
tracker@1.0.4
ui@1.0.5
underscore@1.0.2
url@1.0.3
webapp@1.1.5
webapp-hashing@1.0.2
wizonesolutions:underscore-string@1.0.0
zimme:iron-router-active@1.0.1

Comment: Hi Neil can you list the packages you are using in both projects ?
(Project root --> /.meteor/packages && /.meteor/versions)

Comment: @Nell are you inserting some metadata like `ownerId:Meteor.userId()`?

Comment: @Ethaan I wasn't before, but I added an ownerId field. I still get the same failure. I should point out that the image record is definitely saved to the db (with the correct ownerId), however, the image itself is not on the filesystem.

Comment: did you have something like this? `Example.insert('example',function(err){
if(!err){console.log(err.reason}})`

Comment: Hi @Meteorpoly - I've added the packages / versions above.

Comment: Hi @Ethaan - the callback is not being called. There is an error in the console log "Exception in delivering result of invoking '/cfs.images.filerecord/insert': TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Comment: lets see if the insert its really happening, remove the allows/deny methods

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely happening. I removed the allows / denys and got a "Error: Access denied" as expected.

Comment: I did a small demo project with the cfs packages and no issue here as well (included the same packages). If possible share your real project as a github repo to isolate the issue and to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figured out the problem and the solution is as simple as it is embarrassing :)

Here goes..... don't call your own collections 'Accounts'.

Yup, the reason that `Accounts._storedLoginToken()` was erroring is that it was calling the method on my collection - not the one declared in the, um, accounts package.

I'll leave this answer here in the unlikely event that someone repeats my mistake (and because I deserve it :)